# String literal containing control characters

Tags: bash, control-characters

I'm creating a sort of interactive tutorial that works like the following:

```
echo "What do you press if you want to move one word backwords in bash?"
read ans
if [ "$ans" == "ESCb" ]; then
  echo RIGHT!
else
  echo WRONG!
fi
```

Now, how can I input the ESC character (ASCII 27 decimal) in string literal? `ESC` certainly doesn't work.

I understand I probably better off use another language, but this is an assignment and it's required to be in bash script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of ways:

1. Use bash's [ANSI C expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

   ```
   if [ "$ans" == $'\eb' ];
   ```
2. On most Unix terminals, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to enter a verbatim mode, where the next character is entered verbatim. So, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then you should have entered a literal <kbd>Esc</kbd> character. Depending on your editor, it could show up as `^[`.
3. Use [`printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf), which can interpret [various character sequences](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf#escape_codes):

   ```
   $ printf '%b' '\e' | od -c
   0000000 033
   0000001
   $ printf '%b' '\033' | od -c
   0000000 033
   0000001
   $ printf '%b' '\x1B' | od -c
   0000000 033
   0000001
   ```

Comment: Note: Ctrl-V is the default readline setting for `quoted-insert`, but it can be mapped to anything via inputrc.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can use the `$'...'` quotes:

```
echo $'\eb' | xxd
```

Compare with entering <kbd>Alt+b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to

```
read x
echo "$x" | xxd
```